# How to create global functions in DTM?

Tags: javascript, function, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am using Adobe Dynamic Tag Management (DTM) for a project, and I do not have control or access to the source code of the website.

There is already a lot of custom scripts done by previous employees, and I noticed a lot of duplicate functions everywhere in DTM, whether it's in the Conditions or the Adobe Analytics Custom Page Code.

I would like to factorize those functions but so far I couldn't find a solution.

I tried to put functions in the Settings – Customize Page Code, where we already have the declarations of all our plugins in the `s` object:

```
var myGlobalVar = 'myGlobalValue';

function myGlobalFunction(params) {
  ...
}

s.doPlugins = function() {    
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, `myGlobalVar` and `myGlobalFunction` are `undefined` whether I am in the Conditions or AA Custom Page Code.

So my question is, how do you create functions or variables that can be available everywhere in DTM?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you tried making them window scoped? e.g. `window.myGlobalVar = 'myGlobalValue';`?

Comment: Thanks @MisterPhilip, yes I tried that, but the problem is in the Custom conditions of Adobe DTM, it's uglifying the code before publishing it, so when you call for example `window.fn()`, it becomes `e.fn()` and of course, it doesn't exist.